# How to create array of arrays on click and check by data attribute to see if array exists within array and push to that

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of arrays for a filter I'm building. I need to end up with something like this:

```
terms = {
    'writer_category' = {
        '1','2','3','4';
    },
    'status' = {
        '1','2','3','4';
    }
}
```

I've got so far as pushing the objects to the main array, but I can't figure out how to check the array by the key (writer_category) and add IDs (numbers) into it. It just keeps creating new objects.

It's an on click function that grabs 2 data attributes (one term type and one term ID) and I need to grab that information and do the following:

if type exists - add ids to that object else create object and add id

if you could give me any pointers that'd be really appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your description

If type exists - add ids to that object else create object and add id

```
const terms = {};

function addValues(type, id){ 
  if (!!~Object.keys(terms).indexOf(type)) {
    terms[type].push(id) // If type exist push the id
  } else {
    terms[type] = [id]; // If type doesn't exist create it, and assign an array
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - will give this a go and let you know!

Comment: Amazing, worked perfectly - thanks so much, massively appreciated! Have accepted this as the answer